# Get indexPath for the customtableview textfield

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a textfield in the `MyCustomCell`, and set the textfield delegate in the `cellForRowIndexPath` tableview delegate. When user changes the textfield value and it calls `textFieldShouldEndEditing`. All it works.

However, I wonder how to know which textfield (indexPath) is changed?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {  
        // use this if you created your cell with IB
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];   

        // otherwise use this  
        cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 


        // now set the view controller as the text field delegate  
        cell.textField.delegate = self;
    }

    // configure cell...

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `UITextField` tag in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. If there is only one section in your tableview you can set the row as tag. Like this.

```
cell.textField.delegate = self;
cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
```

And in your `textFieldShouldEndEditing` method you can check the tag.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    int row = textField.tag;

    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([[[textField superview] superview] isKindOfClass:[MyCustomCell class]]) {
        MyCustomCell *cell = (MyCustomCell *)[[textField superview] superview];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        // this is what you want.
    }
    return YES;
}`

Answer (score 1):

You Can Try this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {  
        // use this if you created your cell with IB
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyCustomCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];   

        // otherwise use this  
        cell = [[[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease]; 


        // now set the view controller as the text field delegate  
        cell.textField.delegate = self;
        textField.tag = indexPath.Row;
    }

    // configure cell...

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    NSLog("Selected Cell is:%@",textField.tag);
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```